# I moved my virtualbox images to a new path. How do I fix or import the images again?

Tags: virtualbox

I have access to the .vbox files - but when 'adding' them as machines they seem to still point to the old path which I'm not able to modify...

How can I fix these?

I can't symlink things to the old path because that is going to be a massive headache to move things around...

[image]

---

**Attempt 2:**

I've removed ALL the machines. I've imported the 'vbox' file, and now it's allowing me to change the 'vdi' path. However when I try changing it it is showing me this error:

> Cannot register the hard disk
>   '/mnt/sandiskssd-238/vmImages/64bit/Ubuntu 17.10 Artful (64bit).vdi'
>   {5f70191b-a198-4c62-ab22-d5697b1a2d37} because a hard disk
>   '/mnt/596/vmImages/64bit/Ubuntu 17.10 Artful (64bit).vdi' with UUID
>   {5f70191b-a198-4c62-ab22-d5697b1a2d37} already exists.

[image]

---

**Attempt 3:**

I've removed the ~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml file and tried the above with the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the actual .vbox files (they're in xml) and changed the path listed in the snapshot:

In my case that line looked like:

```
<HardDisk uuid="{5f70191b-a198-4c62-ab22-d5697b1a2d37}" location="/mnt/sandiskssd-238/vmImages/64bit/Ubuntu 17.10 Artful (64bit).vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal">
```